# angular js '?' in ng-src causes infinite loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to get a way around IE getting images from cache while using AngularJS

I have this following code

```
<img ng-src="./individuals/image/{{team._id}}/{{member._id}}{{getRandom()}}" >
```

In the controller

```
$scope.getRandom=function(){
        return "?ran="+new Date().getTime()+"";
}
```

When I run, I get this error

```
Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: function (a){\n\"use strict\";\ntry{for(var b=0,c=q,g;b<c;b++){if(typeof(g=l[b])==\"function\")g=g(a),g==null||g==s?g=\"\":typeof g!=\"string\"&&(g=da(g));B[b]=g}return B.join(\"\")}catch(f){d(Error(\"Error while interpolating: \"+e+\"\\n\"+f.toString()))}}; newVal: \"./individuals/image/51c209ead8b8d863ad69de97/51c209ead8b8d863ad69de65?ran=1371757784485\"; oldVal: \"./individuals/image/51c209ead8b8d863ad69de97/51c209ead8b8d863ad69de65?ran=1371757784457\"","fn: function (a){\n\"use strict\";\ntry{for(var b=0,c=q,g;b<c;b++){if(typeof(g=l[b])==\"function\")g=g(a),g==null||g==s?g=\"\":typeof g!=\"string\"&&(g=da(g));B[b]=g}return B.join(\"\")}catch(f){d(Error(\"Error while interpolating: \"+e+\"\\n\"+f.toString()))}}; newVal: \"./individuals/image/51c209ead8b8d863ad69de97/51c209ead8b8d863ad69dec9?ran=1371757784487\"; oldVal: \"./individuals/image/51c209ead8b8d863ad69de97/51c209ead8b8d863ad69dec9?ran=1371757784459\"","fn: function (a){\n\"use strict\";\ntry{for(var b=0,c=q,g;b<c;b++){if(typeof(g=l[b])==\"function\")g=g(a),g==null||g==s?g=\"\":typeof g!=\"string\"&&(g=da(g));B[b]=g}return B.join(\"\")}catch(f){d(Error(\"Error while interpolating: \"+e+\"\\n\"+f.toString()))}}; newVal: \"./individuals/image/51c209ead8b8d863ad6
```

If I remove the `{{getRandom()}}` it works fine.

Please help.. Thanks in advance

***UPDATE: Please find below the changes to controller that fixed the issue. Thanks to the answer from Liviu T.***

```
$scope.lastMillis = new Date().getTime();
    $scope.getRandom=function(){
        var curMillis = new Date().getTime();
        if (curMillis-$scope.lastMillis>5000) {
            $scope.lastMillis = curMillis;
        }
        return "?ran="+$scope.lastMillis;
    }
```

Comment: what version of IE are you using? This works in at least IE8+ - http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/hakGL/

Comment: I tried in IE9 and Firefox. It does not work in both. The fiddle has absolute url.. I dont know if the issue is because I am using url with './'

Comment: That's not the issue unfortunately. Can you post a demo reproducing the problem?

Comment: I dont have a hosting environment accessible from internet.. can we upload images to JSFiddle?

Comment: No you would probably need to upload the image elsewhere and use an absolute path.

Comment: Can't replicate it http://plnkr.co/edit/WzEndVAUVlKDmMEKZfnk?p=preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I think the problem is the getRandom function returning a different value every time it's called.
Here's what happens:

1. Angular call your function
2. Gets the value
3. See's it's different from the previous value
4. Marks the cycle as dirty
5. After the cycle is finished it re-runs the cycle thus getting a new value ...

The idea would be to have getRandom give discreet values over a period of time.
For example only give a new value every 1, 10, 30 sec whatever you see fit.

This advice applies to many things, actually. Angular provides no guarantees about how many times it will call your functions that are found in bindings. So you need to make them fast and also you need to make sure that for the same input they return the same output(most times, though in this case it might be justified).

Also consider exactly when/how the image might change and if the actual changes can be triggered by something else consider only creating a new result value for getRandom only when the actual changes are triggered(ex: user uploads a new profile image, a timer executes, etc)

**UPDATE**: Can't replicate it in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WzEndVAUVlKDmMEKZfnk?p=preview) using Chrome

Comment: Wow!! That worked,.. the getRandom() was the issue. I have updated the post with the changes that worked