# Avoid Infinite digest loops in AngularJS with random content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, infinite-loop

My basic structure is that I have a

```
<img ng-repeat="img in api.images" src="{{ img.url }}">
```

and `api` has a list of image IDs and has to make a HTTP call to get the URL for each image id from the server. however, these URLs have a HMAC Signature because they expire, and this signature will be different every time you make the request. As a result, the `api.get_image_urls` call will always return something different when doing, essentially

```js
get_image_urls: function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var that = this;
    $http.post(this.url + "image_urls/", {
      "image_ids": Object.keys(this.images)
    })
    .success(function(data) {
        for (var image_id in data.images) {
          that.images[image_id].url = data.images[image_id];
        }
        deferred.resolve();
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }
```

Therefore triggering an infinite digest loop because the urls change every time. What's the best strategy to avoid that?

Comment: Might consider reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222526/angular-js-in-ng-src-causes-infinite-loop

Comment: Saw this. Unfortunately I can't control the values of the random URLs, they come from the server (has to do with S3 permission)

Answer (score 3):

In your case I would create some *pre-builder*. Digest cycle fires each time when `api.images` changes. To make it work, run other process with delay, lets say 5 seconds and create copy of `api.images`.

Something like:

```
  $scope.copyOfImageApi = [];

  // run instant loop every 5 sec 
  var rebuildImages = function() {
        /* ... */

      $scope.api.images = <get promise from service>

      $scope.copyOfImageApi = angular.copy($scope.api.images); 


      $timeout(rebuildImages, 5000); 
    }

 rebuildImages();
```

and after:

```
<img ng-repeat="img in copyOfImageApi" src="{{ img.url }}">
```

In this case your array will be updated each 5 seconds that should prevent digest loop break.

---

*<sub>didn't check syntax</sub>*

Comment: Interesting approach. Is there any way to not do this with a set time out but have that thing call when the digest loop finishes?

Comment: As I remember `ngRepeat` directive watch compares old and new value, if different -> run additional loop. And so on. If data changes frequently, the angular will drop digest cycle Exception to prevent memory lick